# Loading remote content to Kendo UI Mobile TabStrip

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-tabstrip

What would be the right way to load dynamic content to Kendo UI Mobile TabStrip view? 
I know how to load remote view but I want to keep TabStip header and footer.

<strike>I have found instructions from Teleric how to load remote view but looks like they are not using TabStrip but still have tabs on the footer. I was not able to find how to do it in the docs.</strike>

**EDIT:**
I was able to load remote content on Tab click. How can I do the same with javascript?

Answer (score 2):

Loading remote view is easy as:

```
app.navigate( url );
```

The problem why it did not work before (it was opening in fullscreen view) was because I forgot to use div wrapper with data-layout attribute in external file:

```
<div data-role="view" data-layout="mobile-tabstrip">
   ....
</div>
```